# Table with multiple columns containing employee keys. How to link to employee master to get names?

Tags: sql

My table has columns of data that contain employee keys for different departments. One column, for example would be business office, another admin.

I can't figure out how to write and sql that will join the employee master to return each persons name for each row.  I could do it if it only had one column of employee master keys but it beat me

Comment: please post the DDL of your tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think from what you have described you need to join to the Employee Master table multiple times:

```
SELECT A.Col1
     , A.BOEmpID
     , BO.EmpName
     , A.AdminEmpID
     , AD.EmpName
     , <....>
FROM MyTable A
INNER JOIN Employees BO
        ON A.BOEmpID = BO.EmpID
INNER JOIN Employees AD
        ON A.AdminEmpID = AD.EmpID
```